# Is there a Photoshop equivalent to Gimp's Bump Map filter?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, filter

I'm following a [tutorial on fantasy cartography](http://www.cartographersguild.com/showthread.php?t=18280).  It was written for Gimp, and I've been figuring out how to convert the steps to Photoshop (CS6) as I go along.  The step "Bump Mapping your Height Map" on page 7 uses Gimp's [Bump Map filter](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-bump-map.html) to simulate relief shading on the terrain height map generated in earlier steps.

Is there a Photoshop equivalent for this filter?  Third party plugins would be acceptable.  I've tried searching for one, but Google keeps giving me tutorials on how to create bump maps in Photoshop for use in 3D rendering programs, which is not what I need.

Comment: There is a scrip here: http://www.nmaker.com.br/tools.html . I have a try and notice it is like the Menu>>Effects>>Other>>HighPass.

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop uses the **Displace Filter** to create "bump maps". However, I can't say how that relates to that tutorial.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used that Tutorial. This may be late but for anyone else looking for an answer, the Filter->Render->Lighting Effects is the closest to the Bump Map. You will just have to play with the setting until it give your what you want.